Change clock to MultiSectionDigitalClock in MobileDateTimePicker (MUI)
I'm using MobileDateTimePicker in my app. The clockPicker that is integrated is an analog clock, but I want to use the MultiSectionDigitalClock component instead.
I've tried a number of different slots (openPickerButton, openPickerIcon, inputAdornment, clock, digitalClock)
<MobileDateTimePicker
            slotProps={{
              textField: {
                fullWidth: true,
              },
            }}
            open={open}
            onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
            value={currentDateTime}
            ampm={false}
            format="yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm"
            showDaysOutsideCurrentMonth={true}
            views={['year', 'month', 'day', 'hours', 'minutes']}
            slots={{
              textField: (params) => <TextField {...params} />,
              openPickerButton: MultiSectionDigitalClock as any,
            }}
            />

I've also tried:
components={{
              OpenPickerIcon: MultiSectionDigitalClock,
            }}
            componentsProps={{
              textField: {
                fullWidth: true,
              },
            }}
            renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}

Does anyone has an idea of what I'm doing wrong, or maybe know if it's even possible?

There is no prop to directly swap the clocks, but you can change the viewRenderers to show the MultiSectionDigitalClock.
<MobileDateTimePicker
      value={selectedDate}
      onChange={(newValue) => setSelectedDate(newValue)}
      viewRenderers={{
        hours: renderMultiSectionDigitalClockTimeView,
        minutes: renderMultiSectionDigitalClockTimeView,
        seconds: renderMultiSectionDigitalClockTimeView,
      }}
/>


Will check it out, thank you!
